# How to run a command inside a running systemd container

Tags: systemd, container

I have a `systemd` container running, and I can login into it with `machinectl login <container>`. How can I execute a command inside the container directly, i.e. without first logging in, executing the command, and then logging out?

Another way to put it is that I'm looking for the `systemd` equivalent of:

```
$ docker exec <container> <command>
```

or

```
$ ssh <host> <command>
```

Comment: Run a `sshd` or something that keeps listening inside then. Or let `expect` get the password-input job done.

Comment: Both suggestions sound like workarounds for something that should be possible directly. But maybe `systemd` just isn't there yet. A small `expect` script gets the job done nicely. Thanks, @Arthur2e5.

Comment: To be honest, I often treat a container as a real machine and I run `sshd` on say, port 61022 inside.

Comment: similar question (for others searching): https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/302239/4808

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try `systemd-run`:

```
# systemd-nspawn -D <machine-root> -b 3 --link-journal host

# systemd-run --machine <machine-name> env
Running as unit run-1356.service.

# journalctl --machine <machine-name> -u run-1356 -b -q
Oct 30 07:45:09 jessie-64 systemd[1]: Started /usr/bin/env.
Oct 30 07:45:09 jessie-64 env[37]: PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
```

Excerpt from the [manpage](http://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/machinectl.html#login%20%5BNAME%5D):

> Use shell (see below) or systemd-run(1) with the --machine= switch to directly invoke a single command, either interactively or in the background.

(The command `shell` available since [v225](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/blob/1e0adaa45d2c1a300199069bfdeb494281b54086/NEWS#L329))

Comment: Thanks. I have v215, so don't have `shell`, but `systemd-run` works. This I find weird though: In `systemd-run [OPTIONS...] COMMAND [ARGS...]`, if for `COMMAND` I use the path inside the container, I (immediately) get an error saying `Failed to find executable /container/path.sh: No such file or directory`. And if I give the full host path, I (through `journalctl`) get an error saying `Failed at step EXEC spawning /var/lib/machines/<container>/container/path.sh: No such file or directory`. Since mine is a shell script, I can use `/bin/sh /container/path.sh`, but there must be a "correct" way.

Comment: @IlariScheinin, that was [fixed](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/commit/85eca92e2061043d733991b386d8dc10fad0fc30): "It's not reasonably possible to
  look for binaries on remote systems, we hence should not pretend we
  could."

Answer (score 3):

For systems without `machinectl shell` (e.g. systemd v219 on CentOS 7 Atomic) or during situations where `machinectl login` fails for any reason, you can get a shell or run commands directly using `nsenter`:

Example:

```
$ nsenter \
     --target=$(machinectl show --property Leader ipsec-libreswan | sed "s/^Leader=//") \
     --mount --uts --ipc --net --pid
```

Comment: This is a very good option even when `machinectl shell` is available, as `man machinectl` says: "Note that machinectl shell does not propagate the exit code/status of the invoked shell process." Also, `machinectl shell` only takes absolute paths, which might be inconvenient.