# How to run systemctl commands inside chroot container without interactive login?

Tags: linux, systemd, chroot

I am writing a program that does server management on remote systems. While I can run almost all commands using the:

```
$ chroot <directory> /bin/bash -c <command>
```

format and get the results back, starting and stopping the services or getting their status aren't possible because of the `systemctl` restrictions.

I have tried the options offered in these:

- [Start a systemd service inside chroot](https://superuser.com/questions/688733/start-a-systemd-service-inside-chroot)
- [How to run a command inside a running systemd container](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/238478/how-to-run-a-command-inside-a-running-systemd-container).

They're either long winding or not a simple solution like the one `chroot /bin/bash -c` offers.

I'm on a CentOS machine with `systemctl` 2.19 and there is no `--shell` option via `machinectl`. Is there a simple `chroot <> /bin/bash` like shortcut to run start/stop/restart the services running inside the chroot environment?

For e.g., OpenLDAP's `solserver` service runs inside the `chroot`. How do I get the output of `systemctl status solserver` from the host without logging into the container?