# Systemd-nspawn boot container, then run lxsession automatically; How to do this?

Tags: shell, autostart, systemd-nspawn

I am making a script that uses systemd-nspawn to boot a second linux root filesystem in a container.

The script is currently using this line to boot the container:
`systemd-nspawn -b --machine virtualdesktop -D "/mnt/virtualdesktop"`
The host and container are based on Debian and use systemd. (Raspbian Buster to be exact)

The guest boots up correctly and after logging in, gives me a shell.
But that is not all I want - the script should also load the graphics of the guest.
The host has a Xephyr window open, running a second X display on `:1`.
Then the guest will run lxsession on display :1.

It is easy to do this manually by typing this command in the guest's shell: `DISPLAY=:1 lxsession -s LXDE-pi -e LXDE`, but **here's what I need help with:** running that command *automatically*, not requiring the operator to input the guest's password and type in the lxsession command.

I have tried:

- Appending the desired `lxsession` command to the end of the `systemd-nspawn` command, like this:
  `systemd-nspawn -b --machine virtualdesktop -D "/mnt/virtualdesktop" 'DISPLAY=:1 lxsession -s LXDE-pi -e LXDE'`, but nothing happened.
- using `systemd-run`, as suggested [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/239669/369481). Ran this command while container is running: `systemd-run --machine virtualdesktop "/usr/binlxsession -s LXDE-pi -e LXDE"`, but Xephyr doesn't display anything and journalctl reports `Failed to execute command: No such file or directory`
  `Failed at step EXEC spawning /usr/bin/lxsession -s LXDE-pi -e LXDE: No such file or directory`

Answer (score 0):

Remove the quotes from your commands and use the `-E, --setenv` option:

```
systemd-nspawn --machine virtualdesktop -D "/mnt/virtualdesktop" -E DISPLAY=:1 lxsession -s LXDE-pi -e LXDE
```

or

```
systemd-run --machine virtualdesktop -E DISPLAY=:1 /usr/bin/lxsession -s LXDE-pi -e LXDE
```

You try to execute the files `'DISPLAY=:1 lxsession -s LXDE-pi -e LXDE'` and `'/usr/bin/lxsession -s LXDE-pi -e LXDE'`:

```
systemd-run [OPTIONS...] COMMAND [ARGS...]
systemd-nspawn [OPTIONS...] [COMMAND [ARGS...]]
```

Comment: using -b flag makes systemd-nspawn ignore any commands to run, therefore I need an alternative. Similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46443863/systemd-nspawn-send-command-with-boot-flag).

Comment: I have started researching `expect` to see if it can input the commands automatically in the guest's shell.